# What are the definitions of semi-conjugate and conditional conjugate priors?

Tags: bayesian, definition, conjugate-prior

What are the definitions of **semi-conjugate priors** and of **conditional conjugate priors**? I found them in Gelman's *Bayesian Data Analysis*, but I couldn't find their definitions.

Answer (score 19):

Using the definition in [Bayesian Data Analysis (3rd ed)](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/), if $\mathcal{F}$ is a class of sampling distributions $p(y|\theta)$, and $\mathcal{P}$ is a class of prior distributions for $\theta$, then the class $\mathcal{P}$ is conjugate for $\mathcal{F}$ if

$$p(\theta|y)\in \mathcal{P} \mbox{ for all }p(\cdot|\theta)\in \mathcal{F} \mbox{ and }p(\cdot)\in \mathcal{P}.$$

If $\mathcal{F}$ is a class of sampling distributions $p(y|\theta,\phi)$, and $\mathcal{P}$ is a class of prior distributions for $\theta$ conditional on $\phi$, then the class $\mathcal{P}$ is conditional conjugate for $\mathcal{F}$ if

$$p(\theta|y,\phi)\in \mathcal{P} \mbox{ for all }p(\cdot|\theta,\phi)\in \mathcal{F} \mbox{ and }p(\cdot|\phi)\in \mathcal{P}.$$

Conditionally conjugate priors are convenient in constructing a Gibbs sampler since the full conditional will be a known family.

I searched an electronic version of Bayesian Data Analysis (3rd ed.) and could not find a reference to semi-conjugate prior. I'm guessing it is synonymous with conditionally conjugate, but if you provide a reference to its use in the book, I should be able to provide a definition.

Comment: +1. What's the URL for the 3rd edition of Bayesian Data Analysis?

Comment: Thanks! Semi-conjugate appears here (2nd ed) http://books.google.com/books?id=TNYhnkXQSjAC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA83#v=onepage&q=semi%20conjugate&f=false. By the way, how did you get the ebook for the 3rd ed?

Comment: I'm not sure why it says semiconjugate prior there since the prior is fully conjugate. This statement is removed in the 3rd edition. The ebook can be purchased here: http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781439840955.

Comment: @jaradniemi: In the link I  gave, on top of p84, it is pointed out that the semiconjugate prior  is not a conjugate prior.

Comment: oops...I looked at the left side of eq (3.10) which showed conditioning on $\sigma^2$ but didn't look at the right side where the distribution for $\mu$ is independent of $\sigma^2$. As used in this context, the definition for semi-conjugate is synonymous with conditionally conjugate (I'll update my answer.)

Comment: In 
$$p(\theta|y,\phi)\in \mathcal{P} \mbox{ for all }p(\cdot|\theta,\phi)\in \mathcal{F} \mbox{ and }p(\cdot|\phi)\in \mathcal{P}.$$ what do each of the $\cdot$ refer to and does each refer to the same thing?

Comment: Same question as Muno.  Is that supposed to be
$p(\theta|y)\in \mathcal{P} \mbox{ for all }p(y|\theta)\in \mathcal{F} \mbox{ and }p(y)\in \mathcal{P}$ ?  If not, what's the difference?

Answer (score 8):

I would like to use multivariate normal as an example.

Recall that the likelihood is given by

$$
P(y_1,y_2,...,y_n|\mu,\Sigma) = (2\pi)^{-\frac{ND}{2}}\det(\Sigma)^{-\frac{N}{2}}\exp(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-\mu))
$$

In order to find a prior to this likelihood, we may choose

$$
P(\mu,\Sigma)=\text{Normal}(\mu;\mu_0,\Lambda_0)\text{InverseWishart}(\Sigma;\nu_0,S_0)
$$

I assure you NOT to worry about $\mu_0,\Lambda_0,\nu_0,S_0$ for now; they are simply parameters of the prior distribution.

What is important is, however, that this is not conjugate to the likelihood. To see why, I would like to quote a reference I found online.

> note that $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ appear together in a non-factorized way in the likelihood; hence they will also be coupled together in the posterior

The reference is "Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective" by Kevin P. Murphy. Here is the [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=RC43AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA135&lpg=PA135&dq=definition+of+semi+conjugate+prior&source=bl&ots=ulivgzPo0a&sig=W9js1iRYoUpqEgZrlsmcC9CY-ME&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1_r2eoqbcAhUBvFkKHZhAApg4HhDoAQhCMAM#v=onepage&q=definition%20of%20semi%20conjugate%20prior&f=false). You may find the quote in Section 4.6 (Inferring the parameters of an MVN) at the top of page 135.

To continue the quote,

> The above prior is sometimes called **semi-conjugate** or **conditionally conjugate**, since both conditionals, $p(\mu|\Sigma)$ and $p(\Sigma|\mu)$, are individually conjugate. To create a **full conjugate prior**, we need to use a prior where $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are dependent on each other. We will use a joint distribution of the form
>
> $$
> p(\mu, \Sigma) = p(\Sigma)p(\mu|\Sigma)
> $$

The idea here is that the first prior distribution

$$
P(\mu,\Sigma)=\text{Normal}(\mu;\mu_0,\Lambda_0)\text{InverseWishart}(\Sigma;\nu_0,S_0)
$$

assumes that $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are separable (or independent in a sense). Nevertheless, we observe that in the likelihood function, $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ cannot be factorized out separately, which implies that they will not be separable in the posterior (Recall, $(\text{Posterior}) \sim (\text{Prior})(\text{Likelihood})$). This shows that the "un-separable" posterior and "separable" prior at the beginning are not conjugate. On the other hand, by rewriting

$$
p(\mu, \Sigma) = p(\Sigma)p(\mu|\Sigma)
$$

such that $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ depend on each other (through $p(\mu|\Sigma)$), you will obtain a conjugate prior, which is named as **semi-conjugate prior**. This hopefully answers your question.

*p.s.*: Another really helpful reference I have used is "A First Course in Bayesian Statistical Methods" by Peter D. Hoff. Here is a [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=V8jT2SimGR0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=a+first+course+in+bayesian+statistical+methods&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-0KLRqqbcAhVGpFkKHZgAAu0Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=a%20first%20course%20in%20bayesian%20statistical%20methods&f=false) to the book. You may find relevant content in Section 7 starting from page 105, and he has a very good explanation (and intuition) about single-variate normal distribution in Section 5 starting from page 67, which will be reinforced again in Section 7 when he deals with MVN.

Answer (score 2):

If $F$ is a class of sampling distributions $p(y|θ,ϕ)$, and $P$ is a class of prior distributions for $θ$, then the class $P$ is **semiconjugate** for $F$ if
$p(θ|y,ϕ)∈P$ for all $p(⋅|θ,ϕ)∈F$ and $p(θ,ϕ)=p(θ)\times p(ϕ)$, where $p(θ)∈P$ and $p(ϕ)$ does not belong to class $P$.