# Doubt about conditional conjugate priors

Tags: distributions, bayesian, prior

I've just read the definition of conditional conjugate prior in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90938/what-are-the-definitions-of-semi-conjugate-and-conditional-conjugate-priors) discussion but I have still some doubts.
According to the definition given, it seems that the prior distribution of $\theta$, whatever it is, must be conditional to $\phi$. In other words, it seems that we can't specify a marginal prior distribution for $\theta$ independent from $\phi$. 
However according to Example 3.7 of [this](https://books.google.it/books?id=vq19xa-TNL8C&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=conditionally-conjugate+family+definition&source=bl&ots=xiRjpJItVh&sig=kVOozJARK1v64vUaGRvmdkCIm3g&hl=it&sa=X&ei=jZizVJvpGMKZygPM9oLQAw&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=conditionally-conjugate%20family%20definition&f=false) book, it seems that we can still talk of conditional conjugate prior even if we specify a marginal prior distribution for $\theta$ indipendent from $\phi$. Infact, in this example, although $\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}$ has a $Gamma(a,b)$ distribution independent from $\beta$, since $p(\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}|\beta,y)$ has a Gamma distribution, they still say that a gamma distribution for $\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}$ is a conjugate prior, conditional on $\beta$.
Thank you.

Comment: The link to Example 3.7 is not working so please describe the setting of this example for readers to understand without linking to an external source.

Comment: Actually the second link works for me. Anyway, this is the example 3.7: http://i58.tinypic.com/30ud0d0.jpg Thank you

Comment: The $\mathcal{G}a(a,b)$ prior does not depend on $\beta$ but this is not the point: the posterior distribution on $\sigma^{-2}$ is again Gamma conditional on $\beta$, not marginally. This is the point made in the book excerpt.

Comment: Ok, so in the definition of conditionally conjugate family the concept of conditionament refers only to the posterior and not also to the prior. Thank you

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question has already been answered by Xi'an. Thank you anyway for reading.